# Different logarithm value in debug and optimized mode, with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I found today that the intrinsic log function in Fortran yields different values when the code is compiled with/without optimization.

See this example:

```
program test_log
    implicit none

    real(kind=8), allocatable, dimension(:) :: tau

    allocate( tau(3) )

    tau(:) = (/3.221D-04,1.795D-04,1.000D-04/)
    print*, "tau", tau
    tau = log( tau )
    print*, "ltau", tau

end program test_log
```

when compiled using

```
gfortran -Og test_log.f90 -o test_log; ./test_log
```

I obtain

```
 tau   3.2210000000000002E-004   1.7950000000000000E-004   1.0000000000000000E-004
 ltau  -8.0406485016271212       -8.6253353500359413       -9.2103403719761818
```

while with

```
gfortran -O3 test_log.f90 -o test_log; ./test_log
```

I obtain

```
 tau   3.2210000000000002E-004   1.7950000000000000E-004   1.0000000000000000E-004
 ltau  -8.0406485016271212       -8.6253353500359395       -9.2103403719761818
```

See, second element is different. I am using GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1.0.
As far as I tested my program, I found differences with -O2 (though, not at the same place for longer array), and no differences with -O1.

I am using similar calculations in a much more complex code. I think these small differences, in the end, make the code very unstable with -O3 optimization.

Is it a compiler bug, or am I doing something wrong ?
Thanks for your help

**Edit 1**:
I printed my array with their hexadecimal representation as suggested by steve's comment. 2nd element only differs with the last digit: C021402BF47ADFC9 (debug) / C021402BF47ADFC8 (O3).

I also printed the directed value as suggested by Bill:

```
print *, "direct: ", log(1.795D-04)
```

the optimized version gives the right result, i.e. the one I obtain in debug mode. Does it means that the value is changed when it is copied in the array?

Comment: Most of the time, algorithms used in debug vs. optimized compilation modes differ. Even if the algorithms are identical, a mere difference in the order of numerical calculations is sufficient to produce marginally different results under different compilation modes. The short answer is No: this is normal behavior, not a compiler bug.

Comment: Have you read Goldberg's paper about floating-point computations?  If you see this type of difference, it is often prudent to print the hexadecimal representation.  Try `write(*,'(A,*(z16.16,1X))')`.

Comment: It may be a bug of some sort.  I just tested on an Intel Macbook.  My version is: GNU Fortran (MacPorts gcc12 12.3.0_0+stdlib_flag) 12.3.0.  I got -8.6253353500359413 with both optimization levels.

Comment: Try printing the log of the literal value: `print *, "direct: ", log(1.795D-04)`

Comment: Thank you for your comments ! I printed my array with their hexadecimal representation. 2nd element only differs with the last digit: C021402BF47ADFC9 (debug) / C021402BF47ADFC8 (O3). However, I also printed the directed value as suggested by Bill: the optimized version gives the right result, ie the one we obtain in debug mode. So it means that the value is changed when it is copied in the array, right ?

Comment: On my side, the bug still persists with GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0

Comment: This is not a bug, just different roundoffs with different compilation options. There is no "right result" here, all of them are approximations.

Comment: @PierU I believe that you are correct.  I tried with `real(kind=16)` and can see some of the rounding differences.

Comment: Yes, @PierU, is correct.  There are two issues here.  One is rounding error.  The other is that in one case gfortran is using MPFR's mpfr_log() to constant fold the computation while in the other case one is calling log() from libm.